# How to hide text below a certain page width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**My site looks like...**

[image: Site(normal)]

**But when it's slimmer the heading goes under the logo like...**

[image: site (slimmed)]

**And I want it to look like...**

[image: Site (Goal)]

Comment: Why do you want to build a spam bot program? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329321/unethical-possibly-illegal-assistance

Comment: I'm building this for a school project, no backend for this has been developed so this is just an example page.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tell us if you came up with your own CSS, or if you are using a framework. If it is your own CSS let us know at what size you want the heading to disappear. Adding the CSS and HTML code for the logo and header would make it a lot easier to provide a good answer.

Comment: already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get this result with CSS media query. Try this code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .headline {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can assign the class `headline` to the heading text you want to hide in slimmer viewport.

Comment: Thanks, I took the text out and put it in a <p> with that class name and positioned it where it was before then added that css^ and it works great!

Comment: happy to help, keep coding :)

Answer (score 1):

remove html of that tag content with jquery

```
$(window).on('resize', function()
{
   var width = $(window).width();
   if(360 >= width)
   {
      $( "tagName" ).html("");
   }
   else
   {
      $( "tagName" ).html("KBFK - span bot for khoot");
   }
});
```